# Regex match a version number in a User-Agent (without the name off the application)

Tags: java, regex

For example with this User-Agent

```
 Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; fr-fr; Desire HD Build/FRG83D) **MyApp/2.2.1** AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533
```

I have made this Regex:

```
MyApp/\d+(\.\d+)+
```

Which matches correctly `"MyApp/2.2.1"`. My question is how can amend this Regex to ONLY match the version number ?

Thank you!

Comment: The language is java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the pattern `MyApp/` which matches the part before version number inside a  positive look-behind assertion.

```
(?<=MyApp/)\d+(?:\.\d+)+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zM8eW1/1)

```
String s = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; fr-fr; Desire HD Build/FRG83D) **MyApp/2.2.1** AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=MyApp/)\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)+").matcher(s);
if(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output:**

```
2.2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put your version within a group :

```
MyApp/(\d+(\.\d+)+)
```

Or use a positive look-behind :

```
(?<=MyApp/)\d+(\.\d+)+
```